# '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' when using env.step from gym

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have the following code that I keep getting an error saying `'>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'` coming from env.step() from gym. It seems to be the `terminated` value that is causing the error but I can not see where from:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import gym
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import clear_output

env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0", 'rgb_array')
env.reset()


def create_bins(num_bins_per_observation):
    # CODE HERE
    car_velocity = np.linspace(-0.07, 0.07, num_bins_per_observation)  # based off highest and lowest possible values
    car_position = np.linspace(-1.2, 0.6,
                               num_bins_per_observation)  # run the above loop and see a reasonable range for velocity as it can be -inf - inf

    bins = np.array([car_position, car_velocity])
    return bins

NUM_BINS = 10
BINS = create_bins(NUM_BINS)

def discretize_observation(observations, bins):
    binned_observations = []
    for i,observation in enumerate(observations):
        discretized_observation = np.digitize(observation, bins[i])
        binned_observations.append(discretized_observation)
    return tuple(binned_observations) # Important for later indexing

# CREATE THE Q TABLE
q_table_shape = (NUM_BINS,NUM_BINS,env.action_space.n)
q_table = np.zeros(q_table_shape)


def epsilon_greedy_action_selection(epsilon, q_table, discrete_state):
    if np.random.random() > epsilon:
        action = np.argmax(q_table[discrete_state])
    else:
        action = np.random.randint(0, env.action_space.n)
    return action


def compute_next_q_value(old_q_value, reward, next_optimal_q_value):
    return old_q_value + ALPHA * (reward + GAMMA * next_optimal_q_value - old_q_value)

def reduce_epsilon(epsilon, epoch):
    if BURN_IN <= epoch <= EPSILON_END:
        epsilon -= EPSILON_REDUCE
    return epsilon


EPOCHS = 30000
BURN_IN = 100
epsilon = 1

EPSILON_END= 10000
EPSILON_REDUCE = 0.0001

ALPHA = 0.8
GAMMA = 0.9

log_interval = 100  # How often do we update the plot? (Just for performance reasons)
### Here we set up the routine for the live plotting of the achieved points ######
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.ion()
fig.canvas.draw()
##################################################################################

max_position_log = []  # to store all achieved points
mean_positions_log = []  # to store a running mean of the last 30 results
epochs = []  # store the epoch for plotting

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    # TODO: Get initial observation and discretize them. Set done to False
    initial_state = env.reset()[0]  # get the initial observation
    discretized_state = discretize_observation(initial_state, BINS)  # map the observation to the bins
    done = False  # to stop current run when the car reaches the top or the time limit is reached

    max_position = -np.inf  # for plotting
    epochs.append(epoch)

    # TODO: As long as current run is alive (i.e not done) perform the following steps:
    while not done:  # Perform current run as long as done is False (as long as there is still time to reach the top)

        # TODO: Select action according to epsilon-greedy strategy
        
        action = epsilon_greedy_action_selection(epsilon, q_table, discretized_state)  # Epsilon-Greedy Action Selection
        
        # TODO: Perform selected action and get next state. Do not forget to discretize it
        
        next_state, reward, done, test, info = env.step(action)  # perform action and get next state
        position, velocity = next_state
        next_state_discretized = discretize_observation(next_state, BINS)  # map the next observation to the bins

        # TODO: Get old Q-value from Q-Table and get next optimal Q-Value
        
        old_q_value = q_table[discretized_state + (action,)]  # get the old Q-Value from the Q-Table
        next_optimal_q_value = np.max(q_table[next_state_discretized])  # Get the next optimal Q-Value

        # TODO: Compute next Q-Value and insert it into the table
        
        next_q = compute_next_q_value(old_q_value, reward, next_optimal_q_value)  # Compute next Q-Value
        q_table[discretized_state + (action,)] = next_q  # Insert next Q-Value into the table

        # TODO: Update the old state with the new one
        discretized_state = next_state_discretized  # Update the old state with the new one

        if position > max_position:  # Only for plotting the results - store the highest point the car is able to reach
            max_position = position

    # TODO: Reduce epsilon
    
    epsilon = reduce_epsilon(epsilon, epoch)  # Reduce epsilon
    
    ##############################################################################

    max_position_log.append(max_position)  # log the highest position the car was able to reach
    running_mean = round(np.mean(max_position_log[-30:]), 2)  # Compute running mean of position over the last 30 epochs
    mean_positions_log.append(running_mean)  # and log it

    ################ Plot the points and running mean ##################
    if epoch % log_interval == 0:
        ax.clear()
        ax.scatter(epochs, max_position_log)
        ax.plot(epochs, max_position_log)
        ax.plot(epochs, mean_positions_log, label=f"Running Mean: {running_mean}")
        plt.legend()
        fig.canvas.draw()
######################################################################

env.close()
```

This is the full error I am receiving too from Jupyter notebook:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/jn/59brf9ps68b366pxgyt4hpfw0000gn/T/ipykernel_55458/601254501.py in <module>
     29         action = epsilon_greedy_action_selection(epsilon, q_table, discretized_state)  # Epsilon-Greedy Action Selection
     30         # TODO: Perform selected action and get next state. Do not forget to discretize it
---> 31         next_state, reward, done, test, info = env.step(action)  # perform action and get next state
     32         position, velocity = next_state
     33         next_state_discretized = discretize_observation(next_state, BINS)  # map the next observation to the bins

~/anaconda3/envs/ai_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gym/wrappers/time_limit.py in step(self, action)
     51         self._elapsed_steps += 1
     52 
---> 53         if self._elapsed_steps >= self._max_episode_steps:
     54             truncated = True
     55 

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: type of `self._max_episode_steps` is `str` , you might need to convert this

Comment: @sahasrara62 max_episode_steps is not my variable, thats a variable in env.step

Comment: Are you sure you should pass `'rgb_array'` as such? The [source](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/mountain_car.py) seems to suggest it only needing the first argument, shouldn't you pass that as a keyword parameter?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal ah I was missing render_mode='rgb_array'! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. The problem is that the second argument in

```
env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0", 'rgb_array')
```

is a `str`, but it's expected to be `int`, so the comparison in the function `step` defined on line 39 of the [source code](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/wrappers/time_limit.py) can perform the operation with valid types.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting comment from OP for visibility:

Make sure that the keyword "render_mode='rgb_array'" is in your gym.make() statement!